# Устранение пикселизации при увеличении масштаба веб-страницы

Tags: html, css, wordpress, png

Доброго времени суток!

Помогите, пожалуйста, устранить пикселизацию значка закрытия изображения в галерее при увеличении масштаба веб-страницы.

Значок закрытия -- в правом верхнем углу (две стрелки, направленные в одну точку).
Ссылки на оригинальные изображения кнопок закрытия:
[Раз](http://project1.o2.co.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/arrows1.png), [два](http://project1.o2.co.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/arrows2.png)

*На всякий случай, оставляю CSS-фрагмент:*

```css
#envirabox-close {
  position: fixed;
  top: 19px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 38px;
  z-index: 988040;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/buttons-io.png");
  background-position: 0 -76px;
}

#envirabox-close:hover {
  background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/buttons-io.png");
  background-position: 0 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 38px;
}
```

Comment: Используйте векторный значок (svg).

Comment: Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Используйте редактор кода. Рекламировать сайты здесь не надо.

Comment: @labris насколько мне известно, масштабирование на то и масштабирование, что даже svg-изображения именно растягиваются. Это то же самое, что лупу к экрану поднести и пиксели рассмотреть на мониторе.

Comment: Есть большая разница в том, как масштабируются растровые (png) и векторные (svg, шрифты) объекты. Первые - с потерей качества. Вторые - без потери качества, хоть километр величиной их делай. У вас же шрифты не пикселизируются при увеличении масштаба - так и svg.

Comment: @labris подскажите, пожалуйста, а можно ли использовать svg для указания изображения, содержащего несколько изображений (как, например, в моём примере с кнопками) и дальнейшим вибором необходимого с помощью background-position? С векторными изображениями не приходилось работать просто.

Comment: @EugeneKozlowski Неужели на вопросы об svg (что можно/нельзя, что это за формат  и тп) сложно загуглить?

Comment: Можно. https://svg-art.ru/   У вас изображение не содержит несколько изображений, у вас два изображения - для обычного и для hover состояний. Если очень хочется использовать спрайты - смотрите также тут - http://nicothin.pro/page/svg-sprites

Comment: @labris огромное спасибо!